# My contact form doesn't work

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I made a contact form following a tutorial. Uploaded it on wamp as well to test it. But I still keep getting an error, but I am really unable to find what's the error. Maybe because I am unaware of PHP. Can someone please check my code and let me know the problem. I believe the problem is a very small one. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
            <title>Contact Form</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <header class="body">
            </header>

            <section class="body">
                <?php
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
                $to = 'aijaz@techanipr.com'; 
                $subject = 'Hello';

                $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
                ?>


                <?php
                if ($_POST['submit']) {
                    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                    } else { 
                        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <form method="post" action="index.php">

                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

                    <input id="submit" placeholder="Type Here" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

                </form>
            </section>

            <footer class="body">
            </footer>



        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Just a note, as it looks like you are new to php and how to create mails: Please take the time to inform yourself what the pitfalls about contact forms are. E.g. where you need to take care that it can not be used to submit spam.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if($_POST['submit'])` has a lower case "s", it should be a capital "S".

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I changed my button's to small case. So I hope that solved the lower case problem. But the error I am still getting is this.

Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\contactform\index.php on line 29

Comment: @Aijaz because you don't test if `$_POST` has `submit`, which will only be the case when the form is submitted. As you don't care about the value itself you could just write `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`.

Comment: Good call t.niese...I missed that.

Comment: Thanks. A friend of mine says, it requires something known as header? Will this form with the current code work? The friend also says emails don't go when you test it on localhost.